# See how far sheet of paper moves using webcam

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I have a webcam mounted ~12 inches off a table facing down.  I have a sheet of paper under it that can move in any direction, but only in a 2D plan on the table.  I want to use the webcam to figure out in which direction the sheet of paper is moving.  Is there an algorithm to do this?  What is it called?

Comment: Google for "object tracking in video"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest **optical flow**. From Wikipedia:

> Optical flow is the pattern of apparent motion of objects, surfaces, and edges in a visual scene caused by the relative motion between an observer (an eye or a camera) and the scene

Or, to quote a presentation from the Stanford Artificial Intelligence Lab:

> Given a set of points in an image, find those same points in another image.

It means you can compute the displacement of a set of points belonging to the object you want to track from one image to another -> resulting in a set of vectors describing the direction of your object.

1. Find good image features to track using `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack()` -- you should get good results as long as your sheet of paper is distinct from the table
2. Find its corners using `cvFindCornerSubPix()` and
3. Compute the optical flow using `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` -- "LK" means "Lucas-Kanade", the name of the algorithm

See [OpenCV's Motion Analysis and Object Tracking documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) for details.